# SQL converting rows data in to column using single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I am trying to convert one of DB table row in to column and using PIVOT function with cursors, here is the Sql:

```
DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT CounterId
  FROM AllCounterIds

DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @AllCounterIds NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @CounterIdQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @AllCounterIds = ''

OPEN Cur
-- Getting all the movies
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Temp
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 SET @AllCounterIds = @AllCounterIds + '[' + @Temp + '],'
 FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Temp
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur

SET @AllCounterIds = SUBSTRING(@AllCounterIds, 0, LEN(@AllCounterIds))

SET @CounterIdQuery = 'SELECT DateTime, ' + @AllCounterIds + '
FROM 
(SELECT Type, DateTime, Value, AllCounterIds.CounterId
FROM AllCounterIds
 INNER JOIN AllCounters
  ON AllCounterIds.CounterId = AllCounters.CounterId) S
PIVOT
(
SUM (Value)
FOR CounterId IN
(' + @AllCounterIds + ')) AS pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @CounterIdQuery
```

where AllCounterIds is a View that I created using this:

```
GO
CREATE VIEW AllCounterIds AS 
SELECT DISTINCT CounterId FROM AllCounters
GO
```

So problem is I have around 27993600 rows in table now by far, and when I execute the SQL it takes arount 4min and some 15 sec to give me the output and as per performance requirement its bad ... so my question is that, is there anyway where I can achieve my desired result but getting better performance?

And just to let you know cluster indexes are also defined on the table ...

Comment: I assume you've run the sql profiler on this query?

Comment: didn't get your point ... can you explain more and provide some alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's actually faster for your case, but perhaps try something like this

```
declare
    @allcounterids varchar(max),
    @counteridquery varchar(max)
;

select
    @allcounterids = stuff((
    select 
            '],[' + cast([CounterId] as varchar(32))
        from
            allcounterids
        for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'
;

set @counteridquery = 'select
        s.datetime, pvt.*
    from
        (SELECT Type, DateTime, Value, AllCounterIds.CounterId
            FROM AllCounterIds
            INNER JOIN AllCounters
                ON AllCounterIds.CounterId = AllCounters.CounterId
        ) S
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM (Value)
            FOR CounterId IN
            (' + @AllCounterIds + ')
        ) AS pvt;'
;
execute(@counteridquery);
```

The use of `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` is deliberate. It's not likely that you **need** unicode for a list of integers and it will save some memory, thus possibly time.

Comment: giving me following error when running this, error --> The multi-part identifier "s.datetime" could not be bound.

Comment: @dvlpr: This was only an example and may not be runnable directly. Anyway, the `set` statement from the end is your code, not mine. If my version is broken just use yours directly. The interesting difference is only in the way the pivot list is constructed.

Comment: the need of using nvarchar is the requirement by the procedure I am using ... tried to make it as varchar but gave an error saying it can only one of the following ntext/nchar/nvarchar

Comment: @dvlpr: In that case, switch to nvarchar.

Comment: Be careful with case sensitivity. If the system is case sensitive the error may be because the column reference `s.datetime` does not match the case of the derived table `S`.

Comment: @dvlpr: I'm pleased to hear it. As I had said, using your original code for that part would be fine. The question is: Is there any performance benefit to this approach?

Comment: the performance in overall query is not much but yup the first part i.e. using cursor or XML Path certainly differ, if performance is considered between this two ... satisfied, as it is clean and less IO usage in first part ...