# using variable values in where part of Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

Here is the code:

```
declare
    @allcounterids varchar(max),
    @counteridquery varchar(max);

select
    @allcounterids = stuff((
    select 
            '],[' + cast([CounterId] as varchar(32))
        from
            AllCounters
        WHERE DateTime > '2011-08-15' and DateTime < '2011-08-19' and [Type] = 1
        for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + ']';
```

Select statement

```
SELECT [Type], [DateTime], Value, AllCounters.CounterId
            FROM AllCounters
            WHERE CounterId IN @allcounterids
```

as you can see i have created the varialble '@allcounterids' and populated data in it, my question is can I use this variable in where clause of Select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have a CSV string and use it with the IN filter ("predicate"). SQL doesn't work this way without dynamic SQL: which isn't needed in this case

It can be done in one go, thus

```
SELECT [Type], [DateTime], Value, AllCounters.CounterId
FROM AllCounters
WHERE CounterId IN
    (select [CounterId]
    from AllCounters
    WHERE DateTime > '2011-08-15' and DateTime < '2011-08-19' and [Type] = 1
    )
```

But, saying that that, why not just do this?

```
SELECT [Type], [DateTime], Value, AllCounters.CounterId
FROM AllCounters
WHERE DateTime > '2011-08-15' and DateTime < '2011-08-19' and [Type] = 1
```

Unless your question is incomplete and lacks information...

Comment: i m doing this bcz of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076628/sql-converting-rows-data-in-to-column-using-single-table, now bcz of performance I am removing all extra things, and you can see in the post that I have created a view that only have distinct Ids and then doing innerjoin with it ... so want customize this query and improve its performance

Comment: @dvlpr:  1. the question here isn't correct then 2. You accepted an answer on the last question: why? 3. What is the point of this question. And "bcz" is not in the English language

Comment: I accepted it because [sorry for bcz] in that question I ask about increasing performance of the query i posted, and the answer I accepted it increased the performance and I have indicated which part of the query has been taking less time, now I am trying to customize (more the 2nd part of the query by breaking it into the parts) myself ... so when I came across using variable in where clause I asked this question ... and I am just trying to make it better, help me if you can in here or in my last question

Answer (score 1):

I've used this before (DISCLAIMER: I used MS SQL Server, you haven't specified RDBMS), but it only works in Dynamic SQL. Construct a query String, sanitize all of your inputs, and exec.